# Setup.py install_requires to find local src packages

Tags: python, setuptools

I have multiple shared internal libraries that many repositories depends on. Right now, these libraries are in the same git repository and are submoduled into each application when needed. During the build time, I will `pip install the libraries`. The problem I am facing is these internal libraries also depends on each other, but the dependencies can't be resolved since they are in local folders.

For example, I have local library A depends on B. This will NOT work

```
setup(
    name='A_package',
    install_requires=[
      'B_package',  # source file in local folder
    ],
    ...
)
```

since pip tries to find B_package on PyPI.

I have searched many solutions however, I can't seem to find a straight forward solution such as

```
install_requires=[
          '/commonlib/path/B_package',
        ],
```

This way, I can just `pip install A_package` then B_package will also be located and installed.

The reason I would like to have shared library source code as a submodule is to make development easier so engineers can modify and commit the libraries whenever needed. I am welcome for any other suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

**Cost of Publish Packages vs Speed of Development**

The Tradeoff between these two things is the key here.

**Using Git Repo : Good Speed at Small Scale, Problems when it grows**

This is what I first tried in my company. We don't use submodule, we just put git repo under where pip installs packages, like `/Users/xxx/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. pip will always treat that package as installed, and we synchronize that git repo to update that package.

This works great at small scale, but it brings problems when project grows. When you are using git repo, you are using git revision instead of pypi package version so **you need to maintain version dependency manually**. Suppose project A uses package B, they both have their own versions, how to maintain the dependency, two options:

- Always uses the latest version of B, B is backward compatible - Easy for A, but put burden on B.
- Just like python package version, put a git revision or tag in A, people need to checkout B every time they switch to a different branch in A - Painful for large project with multiple branches

And if you have multiple virtualenv, you have to extra work to do.

**Publish Package But Minimize the Cost : The Way to Go**

This is what I ended up with in my company. I setup our own pypi server and the gitlab ci to publish package when a tag is pushed. It doesn't have the problems with the previous one and also supports a fast development iteration.

*For Developer*

```
$ git commit ...
$ git tag ...
$ git push && git push --tags
```

Two commands is all they need to do to publish a package, it's cheap. And we actually use [bumpversion](https://github.com/peritus/bumpversion) to manage version instead of a manual tag.

*For User*

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Every time they switch to anther branch in A or someone fix bug in B, they only need to `pip install`.

**EDIT 2019.05.27**

It's possible to do what you want with `setup.py`. When you run `pip install`, it will download package, unpack it and run `python setup.py install`, so
you can add custom logic in `setup.py`:

```
install_requires = ['b', 'c', 'd']

# make sure it's in the python path and has been checked out
if is_package_b_installed_as_git_repo():
    install_requires.remove('b')

setup(
    name='A_package',
    install_requires=install_requries,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Hi @CtheSky, thank you for your in-depth reply. I understand your point and I agree it is the long term solution to go. Before, we use submodule to checkout the common libraries into our package, as they are part of source code. The problem is that it might need to install unused dependencies for libraries that are not used. So I am hoping to make the package installable so the dependencies are better handled. However, I am really trying to avoid using my own pypi server.

Comment: @Andy You can use the official pypi for that. And I believe your problem could be solved by adding custom code in `setup.py`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Right now, I am placing the whole common library repo containing separate py packages in /common within Docker. I am hoping to `pip install /common/B` then it will also install the dependency in `/common/A`. Is there a way to do it? Even with the setup.py trick, which is very interesting, but I am not certain how to pull it off.

Comment: You can use an environment variable like COMMON_PY_PACKAGE_DIR, set to `/common` in docker and set to other paths on developers's machine. In the  `is_package_b_installed_as_git_repo()` function, read this variable, try to find a directory called `b` and use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) call to run `pip install . ` under that directory if it exists. @Andy

Comment: So you are suggesting to handle dependency ourselves right? Sounds like a feasible method, but it will be a last resort. I am still interesting in any built-in method in pip. I am surprised that pip doesn't have a way to config the search path of source repositories.

Comment: `pip` does provide this ability, you can use option `--index-url` and `--extra-index-url` to specify pypi servers to search packages, it also has built-in VCS support, checkout these [examples](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples). Actually, what you want to achieve is very specific and I suggest you read through the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/). @Andy

Comment: To be honest, if you really want to "make the package installable so the dependencies are better handled", publish pypi packages.